# Cost of indexing on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if its possible to get the cost of creating an index over a column in numerical terms if possible. If it can't be calculated in numerical terms then I would like to know how would the database be affected if I keep creating more and more indexes.

For example here's an index that I need to calculate the cost of

```
create index student_idx on student(student_key);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to know the performance impact of creating indexes over a table, because from what you asked is very difficult to figure it out.

Oracle indexes are segments, same as tables, in your case you are creating what is called a b-tree index. There are other types of indexes I will not explain here. A b-tree index is a segment which stores the column or columns you want to index to,  with the rowid relation to the table for what the index is created. That means that when you retrieve data from your table using SQL , the CBO might use the index as long as your where clause is referencing the indexed column. Generally, an index search is faster because the segment itself is smaller than the table, but be careful because it is not always like that.

Generally speaking, the more indexes you have in a table, the more expensive in terms of cost will be DML operations for the table, because if you insert a million rows in a table, the rows must be inserted as well in all the indexes you have over that table. In Data Warehouse systems is a very important exercise to find the right balance.

But you cannot get a number to tell you the cost. You need to evaluate this by yourself and it depends of a trillion factors.

By the way, if the student_id column is a Primary key, you will have a unique index by default.

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful.